# Внутренняя ли команда в cmd?

Tags: bat

Как проверить в bat/cmd является ли команда внутренней или нет?

Answer (score 4):

С помощью системной утилиты where.exe.
В случае, если команда относится только к командному интерпретатору, утилита не сможет найти её аналог. Например:

```
where dir
ИНФОРМАЦИЯ: не удается найти файлы по заданным шаблонам.
```

А если имеется соответствующая утилита, то результат исполнения следующий:

```
where find
C:\Windows\System32\find.exe
```

Гораздо проще зайти и почитать документацию. В указанной ссылке на [список команд](https://ss64.com/nt/), встроенные команды помечены: •

Answer (score 0):

Можно нарисовать такой командный сценарий (**test.cmd**):

```
@echo off
  setlocal
    set "i=0"
    for %%i in (%*) do set /a "i+=1"
    rem невозможно обработать более одного параметра за раз
    if %i% neq 1 echo:Index is out of range.&goto:eof
    rem ищем указанную команду среди макрокоманд, объявленных
    rem через doskey, так как они имеют более высокий приоритет
    call:isMacro %~1
    if defined $$ echo:The command is a macro.&goto:eof
    rem ищем команду в путях, объявленных в переменной PATH
    call:findInPath %~1
    if defined $$ echo:The command is an external tool.&goto:eof
    rem если ничего не найдено, значит команда либо является
    rem встроенной, либо ее вовсе не существует
    echo:Perhaps the command is an internal or does not exist.
  endlocal
exit /b

:isMacro
  for /f "tokens=1 delims==" %%i in (
    'doskey /macros ^| findstr /irc:"^%~1="'
  ) do set "$$=%%i"
exit /b

:findInPath
  for %%i in (%pathext%) do for %%j in (%~1%%i) do (
    if exist "%%~$PATH:j" set "$$=%%~$PATH:j"
  )
exit /b
```

Пример использования:

```
C:\> test.cmd sizeof
The command is a macro.

C:\> test.cmd reg
The command is an external tool.

C:\> test.cmd path
Perhaps the command is an internal or does not exist.
```